# Most intuitive, readable API / language reference documentation

Tags: language-agnostic, documentation, formatting

I'm working on the dreaded last stage of a project: documenting the API for a semi-technical audience.

I'm wondering: what API docs have you found to be particularly elegant?

Note that this has *nothing* to do with how elegant the API itself is: this is purely a question of the formatting/appearance of the API docs themselves. Which language or API docs convey their information in the most intuitive and readable way?

Answer (score 2):

Python has very compact, but amazingly clear documentation:

http://docs.python.org/index.html

Answer (score 2):

[Django.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to have to go with the [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library). They do a particularly good job of documenting pre/post conditions of methods and excellent consistency across a HUGE set of APIs.

Answer (score 2):

I've always liked the javadocs and tutorials for the [Java standard library](http://java.sun.com/javase/reference/index.jsp).

Answer (score 1):

Two off the top of my head:

- [Zend Framework](http://www.framework.zend.com/manual/en/introduction.html)
- [Python](http://docs.python.org/index.html) ( uses Sphinx )

Answer (score 1):

[Flex](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/index.html)...I really find this sort of setup perfect.

Comment: Yeah, that is nice. Very similar to javadocs, which I'm also a fan of.

Answer (score 0):

A negative answer from me - just to document what I've found horrible.

Maybe it is just a case of living mostly in Microsoft land but I've never seen an API documentation language that I can read as easily as code.

The two documentation sources I read regularly are the SQL Server Books Online and the MSDN C# documentation. I absolutely loathe the technical documentation langauges employed on both. I find that almost 100% of the time I dive straight to code examples.

For example, below is a few lines from the t-sql reference on select - I write select statements every day yet really struggle with this:

```
SELECT statement ::= 
    < query_expression > 
    [ ORDER BY { order_by_expression | column_position [ ASC | DESC ] } 
        [ ,...n ]    ] 
    [ COMPUTE 
        { { AVG | COUNT | MAX | MIN | SUM } ( expression ) } [ ,...n ] 
        [ BY expression [ ,...n ] ] 
    ] 
    [ FOR { BROWSE | XML { RAW | AUTO | EXPLICIT } 
            [ , XMLDATA ] 
            [ , ELEMENTS ]
            [ , BINARY base64 ]
        } 
]
```

It is only in the case of wanting to dig into a very detailed or edge case requirement that I ever take the time to relearn to details of the documentation language. But for myself at least, the actual documentation syntaxes evaporate once they've served their need.

---

EDIT - I felt the need to be a little bit positive about MSDN, I use it most every day and find it to be a great wealth of information, but it is generally the code samples and the explanatory text, not the API documentation that give me the information that I need.

Comment: Yeah, I hear that. I had a colleague show me the MSDN before I asked, didn't like the look of it.

Comment: Just to let you know. Code examples are documentation. They do not appear magically by themselves in topics. Writers create both text and code example that demonstrate how to use a certain feature/class/method/etc.

Comment: @Alexandra - Well, yes, of course they are. The addition of good code examples and explanations is where the Microsoft documentation has really improved over the years IMO. That's the point I'm trying to stress - for me documentation without good code examples and explanatory text is seldom enough. For example, I've always found the technical language in t-sql syntax examples very hard to read, much prefering the code examples.

Answer (score 0):

Python's documentation is my favorite.